# Add custom ui to account details using a slack app

Tags: slack-api, slack-block-kit

Im new to slack app development and did search for a while now but the most customizable ui elements that i found so far were those [listed in surfaces](https://api.slack.com/surfaces).

What i would like to do is add a new ui element to the account details you see when clicking on a users name, but im not sure if that is even possible.
I would either want to add a button at the top or some text further down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[users.profile.set][1]` method to set additional information for a user profile. This might be the closest approach to what you want but it will only allow you to add text fields, it's not possible to modify or add other UI elements like buttons.

Comment: But this would also edit the users profile right? It would not be a temporary addition only visible to me while i look at the profile.